# Need correct syntax for linq to xml query

Tags: xml, linq

I am trying to make a query to first find the node "field" with the "name" attribute "entries". From there I want to get the values of the two field nodes which are children of payload Is there a better way to make this query? Seems like I missing something that can easily get me the two field nodes so I can enumerate over them and get their values.

```
var query = from el in xDoc.Root.Descendants(vz + "field")
            where (string)el.Attribute("name") == "entries"
            select el.Descendants(vz + "field");
```

My sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payload xmlns="http://www.vz.com/types" model="http://10.232.xx.xxx/model/template/61ac3a8b-8e0b-45a0-910b-5929ecc73814">
   <field name="id">
      <value>61ac3a8b-8e0b-45a0-910b-5929ecc73814</value>
   </field>
   <field name="name">
      <value>AddOn</value>
   </field>
   <field name="sort-id" />
   <field name="stage-id" />
   <field name="type-id" />
   <field name="modification-date" />
   <field name="modified-by" />
   <field name="comment" />
   <field name="version" />
   <field name="group-id" />
   <field name="export-rule" />
   <field name="entries">
      <list>
         <payload>
            <field label="FID" name="12abca0d-117f-4046-9f30-f38537a02576">
               <value>USGOV000356</value>
            </field>
            <field label="VosModifiedDate" name="19a282a6-d0f0-4096-b630-ed16aedd1a15">
               <value>11/15/2017 9:50:21 AM</value>
            </field>
         </payload>
      </list>
   </field>
</payload>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is you aren't checking your types clearly. `query` is of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>` because the `from`...`where` provides all matches, and then you are providing all sub-matches.

If you re-`from` the sub-matches, you will get the equivalent of a `SelectMany` that will combine all the `IEnumerable<XElement>` sub-matches.

```
var query = from el in xDoc.Root.Descendants(vz + "field")
            where el.Attribute("name").Value == "entries"
            from eld in el.Descendants(vz + "field")
            select eld;
```

Alternatively, you can select the first match of the top level `field` elements, and then get its `field` descendants:

```
var query = (from el in xDoc.Root.Descendants(vz + "field")
             where el.Attribute("name").Value == "entries"
             select el)
            .First()
            .Descendants(vz + "field");
```